# 'docker run' using mount volume option '-v' with single directory as parameter (no source and destination split with colon mark (":"))

Tags: docker, docker-volume, docker-run

On this page https://mherman.org/blog/dockerizing-an-angular-app/ ,

At some point in this tutorial there is this command to launch the container:
`$ docker run -v ${PWD}:/app -v /app/node_modules -p 4201:4200 --rm example:dev`.

I don't understand the `-v /app/node_modules` part. What is the purpose of `-v` when there are no source and destination split by a colon mark?

I've been reading official documentation:

- https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#mount-volume--v---read-only ;
- https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/ ;
- and https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/ .

I don't see an example and explanation about `docker run -v [some absolute path directory by itself] [container image name]`.

I understand the behaviour of:

- `docker run -v [the source, an absolute path on the host to map to a destination within the container]:[the destination, an absolute path in the container] [container image name]` ;
- and `docker run -v [the source, a docker volume name to map to a destination within the container]:[the destination, an absolute path in the container] [container image name]` .

But I don't get what is the expected behaviour of that: `docker run -v [some absolute path directory by itself] [container image name]`.

What is `-v [some absolute path directory by itself]`, like `-v /app/node_modules`; how does it articulate between the host and the container?

Comment: I can't find any reference but it looks like `-v /path/on/container` just creates a directory in the container. You can try it : `docker run --rm -v /test debian:stretch ls /` shows `/test` directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the `docker run` command supports most of `Dockerfile` commands, among which the [`VOLUME`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#volume)

> The `VOLUME` instruction creates a mount point with the specified name and marks it as holding externally mounted volumes from native host or other containers.

> The `docker run` command initializes the newly created volume with any data that exists at the specified location within the base image.

usually, this is called [anonymous volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#remove-volumes)

> Anonymous volumes have no specific source so when the container is deleted, instruct the Docker Engine daemon to remove them.

when [`--volume` is given a single argument](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#mount-volume--v---read-only), the behavior creates an empty directory within the container

> When the host directory of a bind-mounted volume doesn’t exist, Docker will automatically create this directory on the host for you.