# Docker change location of named volumes

Tags: docker, docker-compose, volumes

I have a problem that I just can't understand. I am using docker to run certain containers, but I have problems with at least one Volume, where I't like to ask if anybody can give me a hint what I am doing wrong. I am using Nifi-Ingestion as example, but it affects even more container volumes.

First, let's talk about the versions I use:

- Docker version 19.03.8, build afacb8b7f0
- docker-compose version 1.27.4, build 40524192
- Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

**Now, let's show the volume in my working docker-compose-file:**

In my container, it is configured as followed:

```
volumes:
    - nifi-ingestion-conf:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf
```

Below my docker-compose file it is defined as a normal named volume:

```
volumes:
    nifi-ingestion-conf:
```

**This is a snippet from the docker-compose that I'd like to get working**

In my container, it is configured in this case as followed (having my STORAGE_VOLUME_PATH defined as /mnt/storage/docker_data):

```
volumes:
    - ${STORAGE_VOLUME_PATH}/nifi-ingestion-conf:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf
```

On the bottom I guess there is something to do but I don't know what I could need to do here. In this case it is the same as in the working docker-compose:

```
volumes:
    nifi-ingestion-conf:
```

**So, now whats my problem?**

I have two docker-compose files. One uses the normal named volumes, and one uses the volumes in my extra mount path. When I run the containers, the volumes seem to work different since files are written in the first style, but not in the second. My mount paths are generated in the second version so there is nothing wrong with my environment variables in the .env-file.

Hint: the /mnt/storage/docker_data is an NFS-mount but my machine has the full privileges on that share.

Here is my fstab-entry to mount that volume (maybe I have to set other options):

```
10.1.0.2:/docker/data               /mnt/storage/docker_data        nfs     auto,rw
```

**Bigger snippets**

Here is a bigger snipped if the docker-compose (i need to cut and remove confident data, my problem is not that it does not work, it is only that the volume acts different. Everything for this one volume is in the code.):

```
version: "3"
services:
    nifi-ingestion:
        image: my image on my personal repo
        container_name: nifi-ingestion
        ports:
            - 0000
        labels:
            - app-specivic
        volumes:
            - ${STORAGE_VOLUME_PATH}/nifi-ingestion-conf:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf
            #working: - nifi-ingestion-conf:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf
        environment:
            - app-specivic
        networks:
            - cnetwork

volumes:
    nifi-ingestion-conf:

networks:
    cnetwork:
        external: false
        ipam:
            driver: default
            config:
                - subnet: 192.168.1.0/24
```

And here of the env (only the value we are using)

```
STORAGE_VOLUME_PATH=/mnt/storage/docker_data
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i understand your question correctly, you wonder why the following docker-compose snippet works for you

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  nifi-ingestion:
    volumes:
       - nifi-ingestion-conf:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf
volumes:
  nifi-ingestion-conf:
```

and the following docker-compose snippet does not work for you

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  nifi-ingestion:
    volumes:
      - ${STORAGE_VOLUME_PATH}/nifi-ingestion-conf:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf
```

what makes them different is how you use volumes. you need to differentiate between [mount host paths and mount  named volumes](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#volumes)

> You can mount a host path as part of a definition for a single service, and there is no need to define it in the top level `volumes` key.
>
> But, if you want to reuse a volume across multiple services, then define a named volume in the top-level `volumes` key.

named volumes are [managed by docker](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#create-and-manage-volumes)

> If you start a container with a volume that does not yet exist, Docker creates the volume for you.

also, would advise you to read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64076980/1184717)

**update:**
you might also want to read about [docker nfs volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#create-a-service-which-creates-an-nfs-volume)

Comment: hello, sorry that was a copy-paste failure. I corrected that as it really is. This are all the lines that are used for the volumes. My problem is not that the file contains syntax-errors, its just that a named volume without a defined mount path (using /var/lib/docker) acts different than when I use an absolute path

Comment: I just don't want to have the volumes from the containers in this docker-compose in /var/lib/docker since in case of a hard drive failure the data is lost. And I'd like to be able to set up a new server, just mount that directory and start the containers and they just use those volumes. I already wrote a cleanup-script which makes sure that the data is valid. With manual copying the data it even worked.

Comment: @25x14: your question is not clear. would you like to mount nfs volume on the host into the container or create a named volume on top of nfs?

Comment: The nfs-volume is mounted on the host. I would like to have named volumes inside that directory which is mounted.

Comment: @25x14: i hope the last update to my answer is good enough for you

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late reply. I would just like to have a named volume, but define its physical location (I have a docker-host with a small hard drive and a mounted share with the storage I need). The reasons are that the data is not lost when my docker-host fails and can be easily re-used when i replace the docker-host. The containers themselves do not have problems with that.

Comment: I got it now solved. Everything I did was correct - the storage itself had a problem.